# How to transform a sequence of integers to .tfrecords and back to a dataset

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, dataset

I have a problem with transforming my .csv file to a .tfrecords file, and then reading said file to create a dataset. Or more precisely a dataset, that gives me the features in a form I can use.

I have my .csv file like this:

```
Feature1,Feature2,...,Feature50,Label
    5   ,   19   ,...,    17   ,  0
```

First row is of course the header row. It's fifty integers and the label is 0 or 1. I'm reading it row for row and writing it to a .tfrecords file like this:

```
    with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(self.abs_write_train_file_path) as writer:
        for row in self.train_file:
            features, label = row[0:50], row[50]
            self.example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
                'features': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[item for item in features])),
                'labels': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[label]))
            }))
            writer.write(self.example.SerializeToString())
```

That gives me me an Example in this format:

```
features {
  feature {
    key: "features"
    value {
      int64_list {
    value: 5
    value: 19
   ...(50 values all together)...
    value: 17
      }
    }
  }
  feature {
    key: "labels"
    value {
      int64_list {
        value: 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And now I'm trying to use this file like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

COLUMNS = []
for _ in range(1, 51):
    COLUMNS.append('Feature'+str(_))
COLUMNS.append('Label')

def get_dataset(file_path):
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset([file_path])
    dataset = dataset.map(parse_function)
    return dataset

def parse_function(example_proto):
    features= {
        'Features': tf.FixedLenFeature((50), tf.int64),
        'Labels': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64)
    }
    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)
    return parsed_features['Features'], parsed_features['Labels']

def train_input_fn():
    train_dataset = get_dataset(train_filepath)
    iterator = train_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    features, labels = iterator.get_next()
    return {'features': [features]}, labels

feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(k) for k in COLUMN]
classifier = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns)
classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn)
```

Sadly - but understandebly, given the dictionary inside the .tfrecords file - this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\REDACTED\Neural Net\test.py", line 53, in <module>
input_fn=train_input_fn
  File "C:\Users\REDACTED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 355, in train
loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\REDACTED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 824, in _train_model
features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "C:\Users\REDACTED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 805, in _call_model_fn
model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\REDACTED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\canned\linear.py", line 318, in _model_fn
config=config)
  File "C:\Users\REDACTED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\canned\linear.py", line 158, in _linear_model_fn
logits = logit_fn(features=features)
  File "C:\Users\REDACTED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\canned\linear.py", line 99, in linear_logit_fn
cols_to_vars=cols_to_vars)
  File "C:\Users\REDACTED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column.py", line 433, in linear_model
trainable=trainable)
  File "C:\Users\REDACTED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column.py", line 1710, in _create_weighted_sum
trainable=trainable)
  File "C:\Users\REDACTED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column.py", line 1719, in _create_dense_column_weighted_sum
trainable=trainable)
  File "C:\Users\REDACTED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column.py", line 2083, in _get_dense_tensor
return inputs.get(self)
  File "C:\Users\REDACTED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column.py", line 1886, in get
transformed = column._transform_feature(self)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\REDACTED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column.py", line 2051, in _transform_feature
input_tensor = inputs.get(self.key)
  File "C:\Users\REDACTED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column.py", line 1882, in get
raise ValueError('Feature {} is not in features dictionary.'.format(key))
ValueError: Feature Feature1 is not in features dictionary.
```

The question is, where is the error. Creating the .tfrecords file was done strictly by the book and the data written into it is in the format specified for writing into a .tfrecords file.
On the other side, reading from a .tfrecords file should be easy and without much hussle for parsing, especially, if you just want to use the high-level-api of tensorflow. In addition, sequence labeling isn't that common to find on google for the newer versions and almost every tutorial uses out-dated tf-versions or just explain the tf-tutorials again (btw, tf-api-guides are abysmally bad documented imo), which use the download-data from mnist or some such.

Help?